# Meteor change data context variable in event

Tags: meteor

I want to change a variable in the data context in an event. This is what I have tried:

```
Template.item.events({
    "click .item": function (event) {
        this.selected = !this.selected;
    }
});

<template name="item">
    <div class="item {{#if selected}}selected{{/if}}">{{text}}  <span class="small">{{message}} - {{createdAt}}</span></div>
</template>
```

When I'm debugging I get the field `selected`, together with `text` and `message` in the data context. However the view is not updated, why is that?

EDIT:

I can do this `Items.update(this._id, {$set: {selected: !this.selected}});`
but I actually don't want to put it in the database... Is it not possible to add to the data context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a better approach:

```
$ meteor add reactive-var

Template.item.onCreated(function () {
    this.selectedVar = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.item.events({
    "click .item": function (event, tmpl) {
        tmpl.selectedVar.set(!tmpl.selectedVar.get());
    }
});

Template.item.helpers({
    selected: function () {
        var tmpl = Template.instance();
        return tmpl.selectedVar.get();
    }
});

<template name="item">
    <div class="item {{#if selected}}selected{{/if}}">{{text}}  <span class="small">{{message}} - {{createdAt}}</span></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I should have to bring in external dependencies for  this, it's too complex for a simple behaviour...

Comment: You can also use Session.set() Session.get() and reactive var is a standard way to do it. This is a core Meteor package: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/reactive-var

Comment: @user1506145 If you want to [scope reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) to the template instance, this is the right way to do it. Don't use session variables if you have more than one instance of `item` on the page. Adding `reactive-var` isn't a big deal (it's a core package).

Comment: What about using var this.selected = new Blaze.Var(true)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want this stored in the database I see no reason to use reactivity or update the data context variables...
You could just use basic DOM manipulation like this:

```
Template.item.events({
    "click .item": function (event) {
        $('.item').removeClass('selected');
        $(event.target).closest('.item').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```